# DateTime Picker for a WindowsPhone8 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, datetimepicker

So i need a DateTime Picker for WindowsPhone Application i'm making but I noticed it is not included in The WinPhone package. Is there another (free) way to get a DateTime Picker?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that describes how to use the WP7 datetime picker. This works for me while developing WP7 apps. It should relate toWP8 development.

[WP7 DateTime Pciker](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Toolkit released at codeplex contains the datePicker and the following list :

- MapExtensions (WP8 only)
- Various Effects/Transitions
- CustomMessageBox
- RatingControl
- LongListMultiSelector â€“ List Layout (WP8 only)
- LongListMultiSelector â€“ Grid Layout (WP8 only)
- ExpanderView
- ListPicker
- HubTile
- DatePicker
- TimePicker
- ContextMenu
- ToggleSwitch Control
- AutoCompleteBox

Go to this link : http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

You Can also download it directly from the Visual Studio Console Using This Command : 
**Install-Package WPToolkit**

Answer (score 0):

1.Open the Package Manager Console from the Tools menu. Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.

2.Within the Package Manager Console type “Install-Package WPtoolkit” to instruct Visual Studio to install the Windows Phone Toolkit.

3.Near the top of the XAML file where you want to use a DatePicker add the following line of code: xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit

4.Then where you want to include a DatePicker control add the following line of code:

or check the below link

http://davidsalter.com/2013/09/using-the-windows-phone-toolkit-in-wp8-applications.html